# Duplicate output when reading in database rows

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to access a sqlite3 DB via PHP and get the output to json.

```
<?php

$db = new sqlite3('my.db') or die("Could not open database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";

$result = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetcharray())
{
$output[]=$row;
}


$json = '{"team":'.json_encode($output).'}';
json_decode($json);

echo  $json;

$db->close();
?>
```

json output:

```
{"0":16,
"team_id":16,
"1":"VfB Stuttgart",
"team_name":"VfB Stuttgart",
"2":"bl1",
"league_shortcut":"bl1"}
```

he put 0,1,2 to the output, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetcharray()](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) returns a dual-keyed array by default: numeric AND fieldname as keys.

If you want just one or the other, then you have to say so:

```
->fetcharray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); // string-keys only
->fetcharray(SQLITE3_NUM); // numeric key only
->fetcharray(SQLITE3_BOTH); // the default
```